# How do I align text in html select options

Tags: html

I have a group of option tags inside an HTML select tag. Each option displays an ID and a name. I want to align the names altogether. Here is my HTML code:

```html
<select size="3">
  <option value='100'>100&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;John Doe</option>
  <option value='200'>200&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jane Doe</option>
  <option value='1001'>1001&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jim Doe</option>
  <!--there is an extra digit; the name is bumped over 1 char to the right-->
</select>
```

Here is the display I want:

```
100   John Doe
200   Jane Doe
1001  Jim Doe
```

Comment: You can't not using a standard select. Your going to need to use a javascript plugin of some description

Comment: if you use jquery, this is a good plugin: https://select2.org/